# IE11 Keep Redirecting to Oracle Java Download Site

Tags: java, internet-explorer, redirect, applet

I am running a page that launches a Java Webstart app and a Java Applet. I don't have problem launching this page in Firefox, but I have to run it in IE11. The thing is IE11 keep redirecting me to oracle java download site. I have install Java RE like 3 times from IE already. What am I missing?

This is the site i am having problem with: http://qa4.kiosk.ieventstest.com/

Comment: *"What am I missing?"*  Information needed to debug this.  What is the source of the HTML in which you see this problem?  At what link can we visit the HTML?

Comment: http://qa4.kiosk.ieventstest.com/

Comment: Is this IE11 in the Modern UI or on the Desktop IE?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20085015/deployjava-js-not-detecting-jre-in-ie-11

Answer (score 3):

I got same issue on Jira when I was trying to attached an image. You can follow steps below:

1. Open IE >> Internet Options >> Security tab >> "Local Intranet"
2. Click on "Sites" button and UNcheck the checkbox "Auto detect intranet network" and CHECK all other 3 checkboxes underneath
3. Click "Advanced" button, and "Add" this website to the zone (if there is something on text box)

GOOD LUCK! :)